# Why do not working grape api for aws sns confirmation?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, amazon-web-services, amazon-sns, grape-api

I am use `Grape` for create API and use AWS SNS, at the moment I want send request for confirmation but my API code is not executed. The request is sent (I'm looking at the logs), but the code does not work. However it's work via `POSTMAN`. Found an [article](http://corgibytes.com/blog/2017/01/31/aws-ses-sns/) where it is implemented through the controller, I did the same and it worked for me, could you tell me please, why is not the code executed for API?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Did you test this through a curl? Please check content type

Comment: you saved the day! Thanks !!!! it was related with content type. I pointed out the JSON, was necessary text